# Yahoo finance API No definition found for Table yahoo.finance.quotes

Tags: php, yahoo-finance

So when I open this in my browser

```
<?php

$endpoint = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";

$query = urlencode('select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("ABBY.L")');

$ch = curl_init($endpoint.'?q='.$query);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_error($ch)){
    die(curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);

echo'<pre>';

//$result = json_decode($result);

print_r($result);


?>
```

I get the error No definition found for Table yahoo.finance.quotes. I was wondering if anyone had a fix to this. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/YQL/YAHOO-FINANCE-QUOTES-not-working/1354972386128-b33f4241-8997-4dca-b750-a1e90585897b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that Yahoo! no longer provides yahoo.finance.quotes table(s). You can see all available tables in YQL console. (http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/)

Comment: This Community table is still available. You have to click the check box next to "Show Community Tables" for it to display.

Answer (score 4):

Add &env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env to your query.

Attention: URL is not encoded to make it more readable, please be careful:
For example: http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("YHOO","AAPL","GOOG","MSFT")&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env